# promise-mysql return promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, es6-promise

**I'm about to blow a fuse with this problem**: I treat to translate an PHP application to Angular 6, however I'd develop this problem in **JavaSript ES6**, for simplification before the final and definitive code. The situation is as follows:

My users' table is:

```
    +-------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field                   | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id                      | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | ip_address              | varchar(45)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | username                | varchar(100)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | password                | varchar(80)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | salt                    | varchar(40)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | email                   | varchar(254)          | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | activation_code         | varchar(40)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | forgotten_password_code | varchar(40)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | forgotten_password_time | int(11) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | remember_code           | varchar(40)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | created_on              | int(11) unsigned      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | last_login              | int(11) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | active                  | tinyint(1) unsigned   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | first_name              | varchar(50)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | last_name               | varchar(50)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | company                 | varchar(100)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | phone                   | varchar(20)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My groups table is:

```
    +-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id          | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | name        | varchar(20)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | description | varchar(100)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have besides a relation like:

```
    +----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field    | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id       | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | user_id  | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | group_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    +----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Well, in this situation I want get all groups where a due user (in this example user 2) belongs.

My JavaScript code is:

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');

var connection;
var arr = [];

mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'host',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database'
}).then(
    function (conn) {
        connection = conn;
        return conn.query('select * from users_groups where user_id=2');
    }
).then(
    function(value) {
        console.log('Initial value : ' + JSON.stringify(value) );


        for (let user_group of value) {
            console.log('Each value : ' + JSON.stringify(user_group.group_id));
            arr.push( connection.query(`select * from groups where id = ${user_group.group_id}`));
        }     
        return arr;
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log('Rechazo: ' + reason);    
    }
).then (
    function (echo) {
        console.log('Echo: ' + JSON.stringify(echo));
        connection.end();
    }
);
```

And I did get:

```
Initial value : [{"id":10,"user_id":2,"group_id":1},{"id":11,"user_id":2,"group_id":2}]
Each value : 1
Each value : 2
Echo: [{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false},{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}]
```

Can anyone help me please? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of `return arr` do `return Promise.all(arr)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for promise chaining to work properly, you have to return promises in your `then` calls for any asynchronous actions. In your 2nd `then` call, you're pushing a series of asynchronous db calls into an array. Since you return an array instead of a promise, your next `then` call does **not** wait for all of your queries to finish. Pass this array to `Promise.all` and return that instead and you'll achieve your desired results.

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');

var connection;
var arr = [];

mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'host',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database'
}).then(
    function (conn) {
        connection = conn;
        return conn.query('select * from users_groups where user_id=2');
    }
).then(
    function(value) {
        console.log('Initial value : ' + JSON.stringify(value) );


        for (let user_group of value) {
            console.log('Each value : ' + JSON.stringify(user_group.group_id));
            arr.push( connection.query(`select * from groups where id = ${user_group.group_id}`));
        }     
        return Promise.all(arr);
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log('Rechazo: ' + reason);    
    }
).then (
    function (echo) {
        console.log('Echo: ' + JSON.stringify(echo));
        connection.end();
    }
);
```

Comment: Good Answer. I suggest that you give Sequelize ORM a try. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/